# Solving PDE from field theory $\phi_{tt} + \phi_{xx} + \lambda \phi\left[\phi^2 -v^2 \right]=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am studying field theory and am struggling to solve this $\text{PDE}.$ I know the solution must be rather simple but I don't manage to find it.

$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,t)}{\partial t^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,t)}{\partial x^2} + \lambda \phi(x,t)\left[\phi^2(x,t) -v^2 \right]=0.$$

With $\lambda$ and $v$ constants and boundary conditions:

$\phi(x,t)\rightarrow -v$ for  $x\rightarrow - \infty$

$\   $

$\phi(x,t)\rightarrow +v$ for  $x\rightarrow  +\infty$

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: What is the domain of interest?

Comment: Do you know the method of characteristics?

Comment: I am a physicist so I dont know much about PDEs or methods for solving them. I tried to use the Fourier transform method but I did not find the solution.

Comment: [This short piece](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/chap3.pdf) discusses characteristic solution methods for second order linear and semilinear PDEs. I suggest you give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only getting started with a course in PDEs but I threw the equation into Mathematica and it found
$$\phi(x,t)=\pm\frac{v\sqrt{2c_4}\operatorname{sn}\left(c_3+c_2t-\frac{x\sqrt{-v^2\lambda-{c_2}^2-c_4{c_2}^2}}{\sqrt{1+c_4}};c_4\right) }{\sqrt{1+c_4}}$$
With $\operatorname{sn}(x,k)$ being the Jacobi s-noidal function, one of the many [Jacobi elliptic functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html). It has many definitions, but perhaps one of the more relevant ones to this example is as the solution to the differential equation
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=2k^2y^3-(1+k^2)y$$
Which sort of resembles the structure of the original PDE, with the $y^3$ term appearing.